Why hire externally instead of converting contractors?
I work for a staffing company and provide "support" (staffing company's euphemism) to a larger organization. In practice, I do the same job as employees of the organization, but for worse pay, worse benefits, worse job security, and a lot of extra bureaucracy. From what I understand, the organization has a finite number of slots for employees. So I can understand why new folks might need to start as contractors, but it seems to me that contractors are rarely converted to employees here. (I could give some specific numbers from looking at old org charts, but I think the organization would consider that information sensitive.)
I'm planning to leave this job due to the lack of advancement opportunities. My performance reviews have been very positive, and I think they even regard me as critical, but I'm not liking the status quo and it seems to me that whether I'm converted to an employee is beyond my control. My question is about understanding the situation where I work. Why would an organization systematically not convert contractors that they know to be productive workers and instead prefer to hire people they know far less about? Cost doesn't fully explain it, as they do hire employees too. These contracts aren't for a particular project or term, so it's not to make termination easier in this case (people can stick around as contractors for a long time if they want to). It's also not that the contractors don't want to be converted.
For clarity: This question is not about why organizations hire contractors in the first place. It's about why some organizations prefer to hire employees externally instead of converting contractors to employees.
Another similar question (though I'm interested in how contractors specifically change the situation): Why would a company hire someone from outside rather than promoting internally?

VTC - although an interesting question the only people that can answer why they choose to do this is the company itself. There are a heap of reasons why and any answe will be speculation

“Why do they not want to pay more to get the same thing they are getting for cheap right now?!?”

It sounds like your contract company is draconian.  As a contractor, I tended to make much more than full time employees including my manager.  They may require a large fee to convert a contractor to an employee which is why the reluctance.

The most obvious reason is that a contract between a staffing company and its client may prohibit such a conversion. The staffing company doesn't want to be the very thing that you propose, a pool of talent that slowly gets diluted of talent as the good employees get poached and the bad ones remain.
In a theoretical capitalist world, it stands to reason that the employees of the staffing company aren't that good anyway. After all, if they were good, they'd be earning more money as an independent employee, rather than being just another grunt in a staffing company.

Unfortunately, to be a good independent employee, the person has to be good not just in their "job" but also in marketing and sales. Staffing companies generally are good at sales and marketing. Thus, good workers let the staffing company do that work.

A temp staffing company I worked for wanted to charge the company big bucks if they hired me after they found me.  The company paid but was not happy about it.

@DavidR I think it depends on the type of work. If you're a manual labourer, likely the company may not want to deal with the whole interview process. They just want people to shift boxes. But yeah. See what you mean.
